# Update a value in an object and return whole object as an Observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an object like this:

```
const obj: SomeType = {
  images: {imageOrder1: imageLink, imageOrder2: imageLink},
  imageOrder: [imageOrder1, imageOrder2]
}
```

I need to update every image in an `obj.images` array (upload it somewhere) and return the whole `obj` as an observable. What I have now is:

```
defer(() => of(obj)).pipe(
   map(objs => obj.imageOrder),
   switchMap(imageOrder => from(imageOrder)),
   concatMap(order => {
  
       const image = imageUrls[order];

       return [order, uploadImage(image)];
   }),
   toArray(),
   map(uploadResult => {
       const [view, imageUploadResult] = uploadResult;
  
  // return an updated object with new links 
        
})
```

);

Which should result in:

```
obj: Observable<obj> = {
   images: {imageOrder1: updatedImage, imageOrder2: updatedImage},
   imageOrder: [imageOrder1, imageOrder2]
}
```

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scan operator (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) to "save" the object state.

Use the scan operator with BehaviourSubject or Subject, and every time you update the image, you call subject.next().

And everytime subject emit, you replace the object in the scan operator to get the newest updated object.